# bootstrap3-wysiwyg editor error when clicking bold, italic, underline, small

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I have a problem with bootstrap3-wysiwyg editor (https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/)

There is an error when clicking emphasis from group bold, italic, underline, small

**How to reproduce an error:**

Go to the page https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/ and click bold and then put some text to the text area. It will be bold, everything works.

Next, reload the page (https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/) and click bold and italic and then put some text to the text area. The text will be normal, and buttons bold and italic will be unclicked - why??? There is an error.

Next, reload the page (https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/) and click bold, italic and undeline and then put some text to the text area. The text will be bold, italic and undeline, everything works.

Next, reload the page (https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/) and click bold, italic, undeline and small and then put some text to the text area.  The text will be normal, and buttons bold, italic, undeline and small will be unclicked - why??? There is an error.

It seems that every even click on the button in this group causes an error.
In fact, after the even click, an html tag which corresponds to the click appears in the editor window, but the text entry cursor is positioned behind this tag (you can see it in the editor window, because the cursor appears there physically)

Has anyone ever tried to correct this error? Any success?

**EDIT:**

I use the current version of the library, but there is the same error there. Above are links to the old version of the library to make it easier to describe what the error is. Link to the current version: https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated repo, so don't expect any updates/bugfixes to come.

use this one instead https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg

The bug you are talking about is fixed in newer versions that are available there

Comment: I am using the current version of the library, but there is also an error. In the example I gave a link to the old library so that someone could see what the error is

Comment: I'll look into it to see if i can fix it.